# How to trigger browser password save

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, firefox

I have an application running with `Backbone.js`, and I need to trigger the browser password save when logging in.

Currently I am using `preventDefault` when the form is submitted, and thus the password save is not triggered. When searching for this I find old posts about using iFrames and stuff, which seems obsolete, so my question is:

How do you trigger the password save prompt, when handling form submit in JS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can force the Browser to do that; What I'm sure you can do is, after the ajax (or anything) post request, do a form submit something like that

---

**in jquery :**

```
  $.ajax({
    url:requestUrl,  
     success: function (data, text) {
       //Request Finished with Success
       $('#Form').submit();
     },
     error: function (request, status, error) {
       //Request Finished with Error
     }
  });
```

---

**in VanillaJS** :

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState === 4) {
      //Request Finished
      if(request.status === 200) {
        //Success
        document.getElementById('Form').submit();
      } else {
        //Error
      }
    }
  }

  request.open('POST', URL);
  request.send();
```

---

This way you let the Browser and the User keep control over what happens.
If you still want to save the password then use cookies, [Here is something you might use](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/)